# Responsive Content stretched

Tags: html, css, responsive, distortion

I had an issue with turning a SoundCloud player and border responsive for mobile devices. I put the height and width to auto and fixed the responsive, but not the player doesn't fit into the border. It also stretches when on the desktop.

This is the HTML and CSS I have that makes it responsive, but the border and player don't fit.

```css
.frame_outer iframe{
  padding: 50px 49px;
    background: url(http://www.dontcursekids.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Border-1.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame_outer" style="padding: 18px; width: auto; height: auto; text-align: center;"><iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/280952276&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false" width="100%" height="220" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

I'm assuming its something with my Css thats throwing it off. Any help or a guide in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `box-sizing: border-box;` because you add the `padding: 50px 49px;` and `width:100%` to the iframe, so for the default `box-sizing:content-box;` the width of the iframe will be softened.

And you can also use margin negative values to adjust the padding:

```css
.frame_outer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.frame_outer iframe{
  padding: 50px 49px;
  margin: -50px -49px;
    background: url(http://www.dontcursekids.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Border-1.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame_outer" style="padding: 18px; width: auto; height: auto; text-align: center;"><iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/280952276&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false" width="100%" height="220" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: full page iframe goes out of the border image

Comment: Can this new meet your need?

Comment: not my question, just letting you know what i see :)

Comment: thank you for your response. as said by the other user the iframe goes past the border.  It does go farther than before, which leads me to believe changing the padding and margin might be an effective solution. thank you for you help once again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with, used `display:block;` i also did a few changes in the html. The image you have used was not great imo, i cropped it so the outside extra space was removed.

```css
.frame_outer {
  padding: 50px 49px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/M57mh9s.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame_outer" style="padding: 18px; width: auto; height: auto; text-align: center;">
  <iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/280952276&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;"
  frameborder="no" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The extra outside space was to make sure the scribble design had room look like it was hand drawn and not cut off. Outside of that, adding the display:block;  works! Only thing not is that it fills the screen instead of fitting inside of it. Would changing the width of the display:block; fix that?